# How to load an image with css using Django

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I use Django, and i am trying to load an image using css.

I have the next code, i can load the image using html

```
<img src="%static 'my-image.jpg'%">
```

but if i try to load the image using css, it does not work.

```
<style>
  body{
    background-image: url("%static 'my-image.jpg'%");

  }
  </style>
```

can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: what is the value returned?

Comment: i allready see what is the problem, it was missing body{
    background-image: url("%static 'my-image.jpg'%");

  }

Comment: body{
    background-image: url("{%static 'my-image.jpg'%}");

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `{% static 'my-image.jpg' %}`

Remember the curly braces.

Also, specify STATIC_ROOT and STATIC in `settings.py`.

And at the beginning of the page load static: `{% load static %}`

Answer (score 0):

use relative path to the image in your css file,
I don't believe {% static %} would work.